# What's the proper way to hide/show AngularJS, or any other single page application ui components based on authenticated user rights?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

I have an application that uses **Spring Security** for server side authentication/authorization, **Spring MVC** for the *REST* server side endpoints, and AngularJS for view.

In the server side I've implemented all the filters needed for accesing all those REST endpoints, based on the user rights. 
My question is, how should I approach making *visible/hiding html elements*, based on the **authenticated USER** rights?

For example I have in the view 3 buttons (*button1, button2, button3*). Each button has a corresponding **USER RIGHT**, that should make them visible/hidden. Let's call that rights *USER_RIGHT1, USER_RIGHT2, USER_RIGHT3*.

If the user has the right *USER_RIGHT1* he should see in the view the *button1*, if he has the right *USER_RIGHT2* he should see in the view the *button2*, and so on.

My approach was to have a list of the authenticated user rights in the client, and do something as the following example:

```
<div ng-if="rights contains USER_RIGHT1">
    <button name="button1".... />
</div>
<div ng-if="rights contains USER_RIGHT2">
    <button name="button2".... />
</div>
```

I am not sure if the authenticated user right list should be in the client.

How should I approach this problem ? Am I doing it correctly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Security on the client i.e. in a browser is next to useless.  However, it should be present to stop the average user from seeing something they shouldn't however the server should be the ultimate place security is carried out.

I'd create a quick directive to do the showing / hiding or UI components and have a authentication service to do the actual logic to determine if the user has the correct rights.

<strike>I'm actual about 60% of the way through writing an in depth article about authorisation in AngularJS on my blog.  I'd check back in about a week and I should have it done</strike> - it might help you with route authorisation as well.

UPDATE: The blog post about angular route authorization and security can be found [here](http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/)

Basically the authorisation service would authorise the user with your backend service it would then store their application rights.

The directive would then use this service to determine if the user has enough rights to see the UI component.

I haven't tested the below code so you might need to debug it.

```
    angular.module('myApp').factory('authService', [
    function () {
        var loggedInUser,
            login = function (email, password) {
                //call server and rights are returned
                //loggedInUser is assigned
            },
            hasSecurityRoles = function (requiredRoles) {
                var hasRole = false,
                    roleCheckPassed = false,
                    loweredRoles;
                if (loggedInUser === undefined) {
                    hasRole = false;
                } else if (loggedInUser !== undefined && requiredRoles === undefined) {
                    hasRole = true;
                } else if (loggedInUser !== undefined && requiredRoles !== undefined) {
                    if (requiredRoles.length === 0) {
                        hasRole = true;
                    } else if (loggedInUser.permittedActions === undefined) {
                        hasRole = false;
                    } else {
                        loweredRoles = [];
                        angular.forEach(loggedInUser.permittedActions, function (role) {
                            loweredRoles.push(role.name.toLowerCase());
                        });

                        // check user has at least one role in given required roles
                        angular.forEach(requiredRoles, function (role) {
                            roleCheckPassed = roleCheckPassed || _.contains(loweredRoles, role.toLowerCase());
                        });

                        hasRole = roleCheckPassed;
                    }
                }

                return hasRole;
            };

        return {
            login: login,
            hasSecurityRoles: hasSecurityRoles
        };
    }
]);

    angular.module('myApp').directive('visibleToRoles', [
        'authService',
        function (authService) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var makeVisible = function () {
                            element.removeClass('hidden');
                        },
                        makeHidden = function () {
                            element.addClass('hidden');
                        },
                        determineVisibility = function (resetFirst) {
                            if (resetFirst) {
                                makeVisible();
                            }

                            if (authService.hasSecurityRoles(roles)) {
                                makeVisible();
                            } else {
                                makeHidden();
                            }
                        },
                        roles = attrs.visibleToRoles.split(',');


                    if (roles.length > 0) {
                        determineVisibility(true);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

You would then use it like this

```
<div visible-to-role="admin,usermanager">.....</div>
```

Comment: I really like this approach, and @cuttlas 's approach as well. But using those rights, hard-coded in the visible-to-role directive, makes them still visible to the client (in a dev-tools like chrome). Can something be made in AngularJS, to erase that directive and it's parameters after it's evaluated ?  Like if I inspect elements in chrome on that div, I really don't want to see "admin,usermanager", hardcoded (In my example, I don't want that the clients should sniff  for the rights they need to make certain actions, or to see what other users could do in that page)

Comment: And also I really don't like that somewhere in my javascript is a list of the authenticated user rights. Even if the server does not permit accesing the REST endpoints, the user could manipulate that object and give himself other rights. Am I thinking to far ? Or should I stick to simple things ? :)

Comment: Yes you are totally correct, however, even if you delete the attribute after the directive is linked 'el.removeAttr('visible-to-role')' I could just look at your javascript code or better yet change the directive.  So you really should not think anything outside of your server as in anyway whatsoever secure.  It is more just to fool 99% of your userbase - security should always be done on the server.

Comment: As Sid describes below many you can use feature based access rather than role based access.  So it would be hard to build up a picture of who can do what.

Answer (score 12):

My approach is basically what you suggest.

You could have a factory which stores the array of permissions of the user and has a function to check if a permission is in the array:

```
.factory('Auth', function() {

var permissions = [];

return {
    allowed : function(permission) {

        return _.contains(permissions, permission);
    }
};});
```

Then you can have a directive, that shows/hides an element using the service:

```
.directive('allowed', function(Auth){

    return {

        link : function(scope, elem, attr) {

            if(!Auth.allowed(attr.allowed)){
                elem.hide();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

So in your views you only have to do:

```
<div allowed="permission_name"> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I find this approach very simple, clean and useful.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a hard-coded list in your templates/pages you could retrieve the authenticated user right list from the server and load it in your scope and then do the same thing that you are doing.
If you are using ui-router this is possible by using the resolve property (that is pre-loading certain data possibly from the server before a controller is called).

This way you can only retrieve the rights for the user that is looking at the page rather than have all rights hard-coded in the client.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think I haven't explained very well my approach, but I'm doing exactly what are you saying. The only hard-coded things are the rights used in the ng-if conditions, and I'd like  that the user couldn't see those hard-coded rights (If I open the dev-tools from chrome for example, I cand see all those hard coded rights...

Comment: Then you can, instead of sending the rights, send something like "show_feature1", "show_feature2" where the values of "show_xxx" are set on the server side. Hence what the user sees is a lot more abstract than the name of the specific right. 
Other than that I think your approach is fine.